# Creating a VR app using DJI SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, dji-sdk

I'm creating a VR app using the DJI SDK.

I have two UIViews, fpvPreviewView1 and fpvPreviewView2.

How do I create two instances of the same camera? It currently only displays in a single view.

Here's the relevant code.

```
DJICamera *camera = [self fetchCamera];
if (camera && camera.delegate == self)
    [camera setDelegate:nil];
[self resetVideoPreview];

- (DJICamera*) fetchCamera {
    if (![DJISDKManager product]) {
        return nil;
    }

    if ([[DJISDKManager product] isKindOfClass:[DJIAircraft class]]) {
        return ((DJIAircraft*)[DJISDKManager product]).camera;
    }else if ([[DJISDKManager product] isKindOfClass:[DJIHandheld class]]){
        return ((DJIHandheld *)[DJISDKManager product]).camera;
    }

    return nil;
}

[[VideoPreviewer instance] setView:self.fpvPreviewView1];
[[VideoPreviewer instance] setView:self.fpvPreviewView2];
[[VideoPreviewer instance] setView:self.fpvPreviewView1];
[[VideoPreviewer instance] setView:self.fpvPreviewView2];
```

Time sensitive. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you are currently doing is reset the view of the video previewer singleton every time.
What you want to do is create multiple instances of VideoPreviewer and keep a reference to manage properly the resources. VideoPreviewer is heavy.

Try this instead:

```
self.firstVP = [[VideoPreviewer alloc] init]; 
[self.firstVP setView:self.fpvPreviewView1];
self.secondVP = [[VideoPreviewer alloc] init];
[self.secondVP setView:self.fpvPreviewView2];
```

Hope this helps.